# What insulated gloves should I use?

Tags: voltage, current, safety, high-voltage

I have a project that will run 20,000volts and 2amps.
The electricity should not arc to my skin, but just in case I'd like to have the proper protection. Will it need to be good electrical gloves or can it be regular thick gloves with layers of electrical tape?

Comment: It has to be good electrical gloves, and more importantly, you should get a proper training on how to use those. You can still kill yourself wearing gloves. That part about electrical tape makes me think you don't know how to work with high voltage safely.

Comment: 20 kV  needs very very very great care and understanding. It would be a really good idea to (i) tell us much more (ii) Not do whatever it is at all until you have competent supervision or are proven competent by an appropriate body/person. Death would be trivially easy

Comment: Yeah - 20kV and 2A available..   if I had to rely on gloves for safely, I would refuse that job for sure.  I would not approach such potential energy without the fuses in my pocket and jump leads to short it out first:)

Comment: Prevent human contact in the first place. Use proper lockout/tagout techniques.

Comment: Some of the questions on here scare the willies out of me...

Comment: Avoid trusting your "Health & Welfare" to a single device. Equipment failures happen, but your life here on earth only once. Rethink your situation.

Comment: ***WARNING: You have described an extreme death trap.***

Comment: @MickLH Wow, _extreme_ death... Is that even worse than regular death?

Comment: @marcelm Yeah, it's louder and with more spectacular bright flashes of light. Jokes aside, my comment is saying that the trap is extremely dangerous, and that some of the dangers are insidious. Haven't you ever had electricity crawl further than expected down a spark plug lead and knock the wind out of you?

Comment: Its my understanding that lineman gloves with even a pinhole in them can render them unsafe, so your probably going to want to do something more than rigging gloves up.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a good document you should read from OSHA: [Electrical Safety for General Industry](https://www.osha.gov/dte/grant_materials/fy07/sh-16615-07/train-the-trainer_manual2.pdf).  Even though not all those cases may apply to you, you should be aware of all the possible dangers surrounding you and what you can do to prevent a potential fatal incident.

I do not know how you have access to such high voltages and current, but you should have training beforehand.  It is crucial that you educate yourself about the dangers of high voltages/currents.

**By the way, a project running at 40000 Watts of power?  What are you building/doing?**

Comment: 40kW is actually not that much. I have seen machines cooled by fans where fans alone would consume 40kW.

Comment: Controled portable arc flash for looks it's going to be a prop

Comment: @Hackerboydh Make sure your insurers know what you're planning.

Comment: You should be using a Tesla coil for something like that. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJBI4XPBaMM High frequencies voltages/ LOW current. There are many kits available.

Comment: Controlled, portable and 40kW of power... Sounds like something for [HackADay](http://hackaday.com)

Comment: Or the Darwin Awards @JvO http://www.darwinawards.com/darwin/

Comment: @Trevor Tesla coils aren't really a safe substitute. First, you'll need real high quality engineering to current limit such astronomical voltages, which clearly the asker doesn't have access to for this project. Second, even with a conservative current limit, it'll still cause RF burns.

Comment: I know @MickLH, but it is a lot safer than 20K at 2A.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane I'd jump straight to "Make sure your will is up to date".